# CSS3 transform - scale animation sometimes snapback on Chrome

Tags: css, transform

when I mouse over repeatedly across two images, the scale animation sometimes snapback. However, scale animation works fine on Firefox. 
what have I done wrong?

```
ul li .image{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;

    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
} 
ul li:hover .image{
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/drunkpanda/6x11cp0o/14/) on jsfiddle

Comment: Can't see anything like that happening. I am using Chrome on Win 7.

Comment: @Harry, that's very strange, I also use Win 7 Chrome v45. but it happens on my Chrome, but works as expect on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `width:100.1%` and `height:100.%` for `:hover` then it work perfectly on Chrome again. 
It should be some kind of css hack but it work for me anyway, here is the update code

```
ul li .image{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;

    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
} 
ul li:hover .image{
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    width:100.1%;
    height:100.1%;
}
```